# Range a new colum from 1 to number of times to appear a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to range a new column from 1 to number of times to appear a specific column, in this case by the column *property_id*.

That's the dataframe I have:

```py
property_id             
1075543               
1075543                   
1075543              
10142620          
10142620           
10142620             
10142620              
10225533                    
10225533
```

That's the dataframe I need:

```py
property_id   suffix             
1075543       1   
1075543       2       
1075543       3
10142620      1   
10142620      2
10142620      3
10142620      4
10225533      1       
10225533      2
```

I was trying grouping by this column and count the number of times that it appears and apply a lambda function. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me.

Any solution?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `df.groupby('property_id').cumcount()+1` or `df['property_id'].factorize()[0] + 1`.

Comment: cumcount() works excellent. Thanks! @QuangHoang